# Looking up the algorithm for commands: MATLAB

Tags: matlab

Is it possible to see how MATLAB implements some of its commands? For example, the "hess" command on MATLAB reduces a matrix to its upper Hessenberg form. I want to see how it is written in MATLAB because every time I do it by hand, it is not the same as the one MATLAB spits out but according to WolframAlpha, I am doing it correctly.

Comment: Use `edit` to look inside the main code for that command - `edit command_name`, though sometimes they don't put the algorithm inside those codes. For example, `edit hess` didn't reveal anything, but something like the image processing command `edit edge` reveals almost everything.

Comment: Gotcha. Is using "edit" the only way that you are aware of for looking up how something is implemented in MATLAB?

Comment: Sometimes the `help command_name` and `doc command_name` reveals some useful info. Other than that, you are left with internet resources outside of MATLAB.

Comment: I'll try those out. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You may use breakpoints and step in to see all steps upon execution.

Comment: You can also use "type" It will reveal if the function is a built-in function. If i use it on 'hess' it will output "hess is a built-in function".